# Width-dependent MatrixForm

Tags: output-formatting

When writing fractions, Mathematica has a quite intelligent behaviour: If the fraction gets too long to fit on the width of the notebook, it is automatically replaced by `/`.

However, by default nothing like this happens for matrices given in `MatrixForm`. Therefore my question is: Is it possible to write a `DecayingMatrixForm` which shows as `MatrixForm` if the matrix fits into the notebook's width, but switches to showing the list when the notebook is resized to be more narrow?

If that is not possible, is it at least possible to have that decision dependent on the current notebook width when first displaying the matrix?

Note that the solution should work correctly also if `MatrixForm` is used *inside* an expression, as in `Table[MatrixForm[Table[f[i,j],{i,1,n},{j,1,n}]],{n,1,20}]`.

Comment: This is a very interesting question; I've never considered the mechanism by which that replacement is performed.

Comment: FYI: [Options which control how scripts and fractions shrink](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/GKumpSk-_ew/bs9RBu48S08J).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a start.

```
ClearAll[DecayingMatrixForm];
Unprotect[$OutputForms];
AppendTo[$OutputForms, DecayingMatrixForm];
Protect[$OutputForms];
DecayingMatrixForm /: 
 Format[DecayingMatrixForm[mat_?MatrixQ], StandardForm] :=
 With[{m = Map[Defer, mat, {2}], mw=matrixWidth[mat]},
  Dynamic[
   If[First@CurrentValue["WindowSize"] > mw, 
    MatrixForm[m], m]]]
```

Here's the raw `matrixWidth` function. It is very raw, feel free to edit and improve it if you like, or replace it by a cool built-in...

```
fsize2pixels = Interpolation[{{6, 8}, {7, 9}, {7.5`, 10}, {8, 11}, {9, 
    12}, {10, 13}, {10.5`, 14}, {11, 15}, {12, 16}, {13, 17}, {13.5`, 
    18}, {14, 19}, {14.5`, 20}, {15, 21}, {16, 22}, {17, 23}, {18, 
    24}, {20, 26}, {22, 29}, {24, 32}, {26, 35}, {27, 36}, {28, 
    37}, {29, 38}, {30, 40}, {32, 42}, {34, 45}, {36, 48}}]

matrixWidth[mat_?MatrixQ] := 
 CurrentValue["Magnification"] With[{w = Length@First@mat, 
   chars = Max[
     StringLength /@ StringJoin /@ Map[ToString, mat, {2}]]}, 
  116 + 0.5 fsize2pixels[CurrentValue["FontSize"]] (chars + w + 1)]
```

Comment: Where did you find out about `$OutputForms` it doesn't show up in the documentation?

Comment: Nice. However, the `Dynamic` also causes the matrix to track all future assignments; e.g. for `DecayingMatrixForm[Table[f[i,j],{i,1,10},{j,1,10}]]` on subsequent defining `f[1,1]=3` the displayed value for the first matrix element also changes to 3. Maybe wrapping the individual matrix elements in `HoldForm` would help.

Comment: @celtschk, edited, give ti a try

Comment: @rcollyer, I guess it was about a  month ago when I was investigating the forms. I came into `$BoxForms`, because of an error message, and then intuitively tried `Names["$*Forms"]` to get a very interesting result

Comment: `$OutputForms` contains `$PrintForms` which contain `$BoxForms`. `$OutputForms` has all those forms that output with the `//*Form` `CellLabel`. `$PrintForms` all those that work with `ToString`, and `$BoxForms` the input box forms that you can add to `MakeBoxes`, etc

Comment: `$PrintForms` is `Locked`, but the other two are unprotectable. You can however add a print form just by making a `Format` definition with your custom form. And well, there are some other subtleties around

Comment: that I didn't dig much... Context issues... `ParentForm` is a quick way to define your own form based on an already defined one

Comment: Interesting. Looks like I may have to re-implement [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3978149/198315) at some point.

Comment: @Rojo: While it now doesn't change immediately on redefining `f[1,1]`, it still changes as soon as the window is resized afterwards.

Comment: @celtschk, there

Comment: @Rojo: Now it works great.

Comment: @celtschk thanks for the accept